# In which tables values will be inserted if I insert values into a view that its result is made out of inner join of 3 tables?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Ι have the following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_view as 
SELECT
  col1,
  col11
from
  table_a JOIN table_b on table_a.id=table_b.a_id
  join
   (
     select id,col56 from table_c where col56 > 3
   ) as filtered_c on table_a.id=filtered_c.a_id;
```

table_a is:

```
id: SERIAL PK
col1: INTEGER
```

table_b is:

```
id: SERIAL PK
col11: INTEGER
a_id FK table_a
```

table_c is:

```
id: SERIAL PK
col56 INTEGER
a_id FK table_a
```

As I saw upon postgresql [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Updatable_views) I can insert values to views that correspond to the appropriate tables. But in my case if I insert:

```
INSERT INTO my_view VALUES (7,88);
```

In which table the values will be inserted? As far as I know views are read-only tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view that contains a join is not automatically updatable, that is, you cannot simply insert into such a view. The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS) says (emphasis mine):

> A view is automatically updatable if it satisfies all of the following conditions:
>
> - The view must have **exactly one entry** in its `FROM` list, which must be a table or another updatable view.
> - The view definition must not contain `WITH`, `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `LIMIT`, or `OFFSET` clauses at the top level.
> - The view definition must not contain set operations (`UNION`, `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT`) at the top level.
>
> The view's select list must not contain any aggregates, window functions or set-returning functions.

The only way to insert into a view that does not meet these requirements is to create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on it, in which case what valuees go to what tables is determined by the logic implemented in that trigger.